En C, ¿hay una forma de validar que el usuario no ingrese decimales?
Por ejemplo, si se ingresa un 5.6, que salga un mensaje de error y lo vuelva a pedir.
Podría ser en un ciclo while, pero no se muy bien cual seria la condición.
Gracias por su ayuda de antemano:)

Para eso tendrás que leer de caracter a caracter la entrada (recomiendo la función getchar de stdio.h) y si consigues una "," o un "." das tu respectivo mensaje de error y despues transforma a entero con atoi

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Aceptar sólo números
